# how send server data in a multi page web application?

Tags: javascript, html, json, dom, fetch

These days I made a standard home page, a login page, and a user information page. In my login page using method POST and Ajax(Fetch), I send the e-mail and password to the server, the server responses the correct json with the user information that belongs to that e-mail. BUT I don't have an idea how that user information in JSON can use in another HTML document like a user information page.
I have tried so many things but nothing helped me.

```
form.addEventListener('submit',(e)=>{

e.preventDefault();

    const data={}

    data1.correo=email.value;
    data1.contrasenia=password.value;


        const miinit={
        method:'POST',                    
        headers: {"Content-type":"application/json"},
        body:JSON.stringify(data1)}

        const url='https://localhost:44351/api/login';

        const myrequest =new Request(url,miinit)

    const requestpost=()=>{

        fetch(myrequest).then(response=>{console.log(response);return response.json()}).then(response=>{console.log(response)})
    }    

    requestpost()
})
```

Comment: Just a guess too, but SO está también en español o portugues, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/  https://es.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: What do you mean yo udon't know how to use the JSON data in another html document? Do you need to access the DOM of another page and update the properties of elements related to the user's information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you are doing this all without any library or anything. With that being said, I'm assuming that each page transition is going to be a full page refresh. This means that your object returned by the API is only as good as the lifetime of your Login Page.

You have two options that will work with your setup:

1. Use `localStorage` to store the current users JSON payload.

```js
const payload = { userId: 1, name: 'Test' };
// The item being saved to localStorage must be
// a string. You serialize/deserialize as your
// set/get if need be.
localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(payload));

// On some other page, calling localStorage.getItem
// will give you the object
console.log(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
```

2. Assuming you have control of your backend code and there is a session available, create a new API Method that will return the current user object. You can call the `getCurrentUser` method on every page and that will return that logged in user.

Both of these options have security points to think about, but that isn't what this question is about. I think for you, the easiest option is to just save the object to Local Storage, but **I would not recommend** that for a production setup. If you are trying to do something that is production ready, I would recommend that you look into JWT Authentication.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

https://jwt.io/introduction/

Comment: thanks man, and another question. Why you don't recommend local storage for a production setup?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the information coming back from the server in more than one page, you'd have to store it in [LocalStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) or another persistent API. Data is not shared across pages.